# getRealPath("/") not working in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jakarta-ee

Am working on spring boot applicaiton. I want to write a jsp files dynamically into the web content. So i took the real path from the ServletContext and write into it. It is working fine in eclipse.

```
@autowired
ServletContext context
```

or

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String targetPath = context.getRealPath("/default/pages");
```

But I try to deploy a war file on linux machine, the path is empty. Please     help me to fix this or let me know if it possible to do ?

```
spring boot embedded tomcat
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the "/" sign means root directory of the whole system. String is trying to find  "/default/pages" from the root. So may be try classpath: ?

Comment: classpath will have java files only right. I want to write into the webcontents. getRealPath("/default/pages") @RedCollarPanda

Comment: Any file access permissions? Can you check them?

Comment: using as root user only. having all permission @RedCollarPanda

Comment: There are many similar questions on situations when `getRealPath` does not work here on SO. Please check other questions and answers. Also you did not specify your application server / servlet container. AFAIK the real path does not work if your servlet container does not unpack the WAR (i.e. you can not get real path for files inside a WAR).

Comment: am using spring boot embedded tomcat @PavelHoral

Comment: So you are packing everything inside JAR. No support for real path there. `getRealPath` should return file system path for the resource, but no path can represent file inside JAR archive. Maybe ask a different question with your actual goal (what are you trying to achieve).

Comment: I want to dynamically add HTML, CSS and JS inside the WAR on run time and access it on run time itself. @PavelHoral

Comment: Then you probably need to have a separate folder for that. I don't think it is possible (at least not easily achievable) to modify JAR on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons not to rely on `getRealPath()` in real-world deployments.  There are several better approaches, depending on your use-case; but the one that worked best for me was to use a file path from the `application.properties` file using `@Value`